# Conversion of a LINQ query fom method syntax to query syntax

Tags: linq, syntax

Hi I am changing career to computer programming. I am still in college. I have to change the following LINQ query from method syntax to query syntax. What gets me is the 2 steps process of the method query. First it gets a teamId and then it returns a list based on the context and using the teamId. I am confused about how to translate this to query method. Most of the questions are about going from query syntax to method.

Can someone Help?

```
    public IEnumerable<TemplateView> GetTemplates(Guid userId, int languageId)
    {
        using (DigigateEntities context = new Models.DigigateEntities())
        {
            var teamId = context
                            .TeamMembers
                            .Include("Team")
                            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == userId)
                            .Team.Id;

            return context
                        .TeamTemplates.Include("Template")
                                .Where(c => c.TeamId == teamId)
                                .Select(c => c.Template)
                                .Where(c => c.StatusId == 1/*Active*/)
                                    .Select(k => new TemplateView
                                    {
                                        TemplateName = k.Name,
                                        Id = k.Id,
                                        IsCustom = k.Custom,
                                        TypeId = k.TypeId,
                                        TypeName = k.TemplateType.Description,
                                        FileName = k.FileName,
                                        TemplateImage = "test.png",
                                        LanguageId = k.LanguageId,
                                        LanguageName = k.Language.Name,
                                        CreateDate = k.CreateDate
                                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean SQL query? You should tag with then. Also you could provide the Schema so you get your answer.

Comment: You are right, I will try to add the tag... Thanks!  François

Comment: @MillerKoijam, LINQ query syntax is different from SQL query syntax. The SQL tag is inappropriate for this question.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg It doesn't matter what db is in use. There are 2 types of syntax for writing LINQ queries, and they are database agnostic.

Comment: I am using SQL Server.

Comment: @MillerKoijam Sorry about the tags, I am totally new at this...

Answer (score 0):

The first one is pretty straight forward. I delayed the execution of the query until the end. Since you may get a null reference exception in your example accessing `.FirstOrDefault().Team.Id;`

```
var teamId = (from c in context.TeamMembers.Include("Team")
             where c.UserId == userId
             select c.Team.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

This one you just need to use an `into` in order to continue your query statement

```
return (from c in context.TeamTemplates.Include("Template")
       where c.TeamId == teamId
       select c.Template into k
       where k.StatusId == 1
       select new TemplateView
       {
         TemplateName = k.Name,
         Id = k.Id,
         IsCustom = k.Custom,
         TypeId = k.TypeId,
         TypeName = k.TemplateType.Description,
         FileName = k.FileName,
         TemplateImage = "test.png",
         LanguageId = k.LanguageId,
         LanguageName = k.Language.Name,
         CreateDate = k.CreateDate
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! Much appreciated. François

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<TemplateView> GetTemplates(Guid userId, int languageId)
{
    using (DigigateEntities context = new Models.DigigateEntities())
    {
        var teamId = (from tm in context.TeamMembers.Include("Team")
                     where tm.UserId==userId
                     select tm.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        IEnumerable<TemplateView> result = from k in (from tmp in context.TeamTemplates.Include("Template")
                                                      select tmp.Template)
                                           where k.StatusId==1
                                           select new
                                           {

                                               TemplateName = k.Name,
                                               Id = k.Id,
                                               IsCustom = k.Custom,
                                               TypeId = k.TypeId,
                                               TypeName = k.TemplateType.Description,
                                               FileName = k.FileName,
                                               TemplateImage = "test.png",
                                               LanguageId = k.LanguageId,
                                               LanguageName = k.Language.Name,
                                               CreateDate = k.CreateDate
                                           };
        return result;
    }
```